# What is the meaning of a unique expression?

Tags: polynomials

It’s a very simple question:

> A monic polynomial of degree 2 has a double root at x=-4. Write down an expression for the polynomial P(x). Is this a unique expression?

I know it must be $P(x)=(x+4)^2$, but what does a unique expression mean? Is it, because it’s monic there is only one possible answer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they mean that $P(x) = (x+4)^2$ is that only possible solution.  So it is unique.  They are asking if it is unique.  If they omitted it was degree $2$ the $P(x) = Q(x)(x+4)^2$ for any polynomial $Q(x)$ and that is *not* unique.  If they omitted it was monic then $P(x) = c(x+4)^2$ for any none zero $c$ and that is not unique.  But **is**  $(x+4)^2$ the only possible monic second degree polynomial with a double root at $-4$?

Answer (score 1):

Each polynomial of the form $c(x+4)^2$, with $c \ne 0$, has a double root at $x=-4$.

If $c(x+4)^2$ is monic, then $c=?$